# aam-opencv compile failed with OpenCVConfig.cmake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, makefile, cmake

Following is the link to the project http://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/

I am trying to compile this project on Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenCV 2.4.9. I have generated the CMake files successfully but when I start to compile it using make I get compilation error . I am using the new OpenCVConfig.cmake which I copied from /usr/local/share/OpenCV folder for compilation.I have made the necessary changes in CMakeLists.txt too. Any Help will be appreciated.
I am getting the following dump on compile.

```
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qt-aamtrainer.dir/src/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/aam-opencv-read-only/include/lkFitting.h:22:0,
                 from /home/aam-opencv-read-only/src/main.cpp:34:
/home/aam-opencv-read-only/include/delaunay.h:130:44: error: ‘CvSubdiv2DEdge’ has not been declared<br>
/home/aam-opencv-read-only/include/delaunay.h:135:5: error: ‘CvSubdiv2D’ does not name a type<br>
/home/aam-opencv-read-only/include/delaunay.h:137:5: error: ‘CvSubdiv2D’ does not name a type<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV 2.4.3 is the current official & stable release, not 2.4.9.

To solve that compiling error, simply edit `delaunay.h` and add:

```
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"
```

Comment: Thanks karl for your help. It didn't resolve my issue but just gave me the right clue needed. I needed to include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp". In my OpenCV Version , the declarations are present in this file. Thanks Once Again. you can edit the answer.I will accept it after that.

Comment: Right, well observed. Thanks!